# Export WPF datagrid to PDF-file

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, datagrid, save

I'm writing an program in WPF that puts data from an mySQL-database into an datagrid.

The data that comes out of the database, is saved in an list of objects.
This list is the datasource for the datagrid.

Now i want to save this content to a PDF-file.

What's the best solution to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution depends heavily on your specific requirements. A few of the things you should think about when considering a solution are:

1. How important is performance? If this is a server side task (probably not based on your info above) then you would really care about high performance to minimize load on your server.
2. How much customization of the reports do you need?
3. Do you need the report engine to format the data beyond what comes back from MySQL or the container object being used to transport the data? For example, currency, percentages, etc ...
4. What is your budget? Do you have room for a paid solution?

In general, there are a lot of solutions out there. Some of them will even take a standard DataTable or DataSet and generate the report from that. Typically though, with a solution like this you lose some level of customization over the report in exchange for the ease of implementation.

I personally have used iTextSharp in the past. It is really easy to generate a table based on your tabular data and you maintain absolute control over the PDF document being generated. Unfortunately, iTextSharp appears to have moved more into the private sphere and isn't really practical for most uses due to their ridiculous pricing and requirements on the Community Edition.

Comment: Hi Shawn, thanks for the answer.

This needs to work at the clientside. The only customization that's needed, is formatting as currency and adding a logo (picture).

It may cost something.

Comment: If that’s the case I would go with something line IronPDF and generate your report using HTML. Pretty cheap one-time license fee and generating an HTML table for your data will be a piece of cake.

Comment: Hi Shawn, thanks for the quick answers. This resolved my problem :)